# confidence interval for multiple choice

Tags: binomial-distribution, confidence-interval

In a wine competition each participant is required to look at $m$ glasses of (different) wine and choose which one is a Bordeaux. Each participant does so $Q=20$ times and collect 1 point for each correct answer, 0 otherwise.
There are participant who do not know about wines, so their probability to get 1 point for each question is $1/m$.

A participant passes if she/he gets 50% of questions right (that is, 10 or more out of 20).

I need to choose $m$ such that the the probability that someone who does not know about wines passes is less or equal than 50% with a 95% confidence interval.

---

My attempt:

Let $p$ be the probability of success (that is $1/m$) for each question for someone who doesn't know wines.

Facts: the expected value for each of them on the $Q=20$ consecutive questions is $\mu=Qp$ and the variance is $\sigma^2=Qp(1-p)$ (a binomial distribution).

For $n$ participants I would know that their results' mean is normal with mean equal to $\mu$ and variance equal to $\sigma^2/n$, so I would build the 95% confidence interval as $[-2\sigma/\sqrt{n}, 2\sigma/\sqrt{n}]$.

Then I would solve the equation $2\sigma/\sqrt{n} \leq 0.5$ (the upper bound of the CI smaller than the maximum wanted probability) and compute $p$, and then $m$.

However, without the knowledge of $n$ I don't know how to build the standard error $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ (from which the confidence interval).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$n = 20$ is the number of trials. So for a normal approximation solve for a maximum m the inequality $\frac{20}{m} + 1.96\cdot \sqrt{\frac{20}{m}(1-\frac{1}{m})}< 10$

I was just checking the equation. The probability interval for a normal approximation is

$p \pm z\sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$ where $p = \frac{1}{m}$

$\frac{1}{m} \pm 1.96\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{m}(1-\frac{1}{m})}{20}}$

Converting this to expected values:

$\frac{20}{m} \pm 1.96\cdot \sqrt{\frac{\frac{1}{m}(1-\frac{1}{m})}{20}}\cdot 20$

$= \frac{20}{m} \pm 1.96\cdot \sqrt{\frac{20}{m}(1-\frac{1}{m})}$

Comment: where is $<10$ coming from?
Also, I thought about $n=Q=20$, but I don't get the logic: what I know from theory is that if I ask to a big number of people to answer the 20 questions then the average of their individual result will be distributed as a normal with mean equal to the "real" (population) average, and variance equal to "real" variance divided by the same "big number". How it comes this big number is also = $n$?

Comment: I get the <10 part now. Can you please clarify my second question in the comment above? Thanks!  @PhilH

Comment: I think you are confusing population with trials. For coin tossing, which this is essentially, the statistics and outcomes are based on the number of coin tosses in a series and not on the number of people who repeat the series.

Comment: Confidence interval is always "estimate +- 2*SE" (standard error). I have troubles in understanding why in your solution the SE is $\sqrt{np(1−p)}$, which is the standard deviation for a bernoulli distribution. SE should be the sd divided by the sample size (under square root). Can you please elaborate this point? @PhilH

Comment: See above edit adding explanation of formula.

Comment: OK, thanks @PhilH ! I think I got it now and believe the way a statistic student would like to read that is: (1) getting score 1 in a single question is a Bernoulli(p) random variable; (2) getting a score $\geq S$ out of $n=20$ question is a binomial var; (3) such binomial variable has mean $np$ and variance $np(1-p)$; (4) it can be approximated with a normal with same mean and same variance (but under which hypothesis? Can you help on this?); (5) the s.d. of such normal is $\sigma=\sqrt{np(1-p)}$; (6) a 95% confidence interval means being far from the mean by $1.96 \sigma$.. and that's it

Comment: It sounds reasonable. A binomial distribution can be approximated to a normal distribution if n is large and if p isn't close to 0 or 1. Some texts say close to 1/2 and give no definitive number for large. The answer to your specific problem is m = 4. Calculating the actual probability of getting 10 out of 20 correct by guessing is then $^{20}C_{10}\cdot .25^{10}\cdot .75^{10} = .01$

Comment: Cool, now your answer is 100% clear! I marked it as approved (btw how funny someone gave -1 to my question!) Thanks @PhilH